# Raw query CASE WHEN is not working in Lumen?

Tags: sql, laravel, lumen, case-when

I want to use CASE WHEN in Lumen, but it returns the message "Oops! An Error Occurred. The server returned a 500 Internal Server Error."

```
//Working
$result = DB::table('Users')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count'))
    ->where('user_id', 'A1')        
    ->get();
```

```
// Working
$result = DB::select('SELECT CASE WHEN user_status="new" THEN "New"  ELSE "Expired" END AS new_status FROM Users WHERE user_id="A1"');
```

```
//Failed
$result = DB::table('Users')
    ->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN user_status="new" THEN "New"  ELSE "Expired" END AS new_status'))
    ->where('user_id', 'A1')        
    ->get();
```

Why did it fail?

Lumen 7.0

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your second query works, because it has syntax errors?

Comment: What is your database ?

Comment: @jack check log file , that query is working.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova U are right, sorry for the typo. Should be single quotes, changed. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @VBoka the DB is MS SQL

Comment: @NC64 Invalid column name "new", i found the problem, the brackets & the quotes. I will update later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
//Try
$result = DB::table('Users')
    ->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN user_status=''new'' THEN ''New''  ELSE ''Expired'' END AS new_status'))
    ->where('user_id', 'A1')        
    ->get();

//Try2
$result = DB::table('Users')
    ->select(DB::raw("(CASE WHEN (user_status='new') THEN 'New'  ELSE 'Expired' END) AS new_status"))
    ->where('user_id', 'A1')        
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hi, changed double quotes to two single quotes? Same error.

Comment: Hi @Jack , I have added one more "Try"

Comment: Thanks, It solved. there are two ways to fix the issue, the first way is your solution, added brackets and the second way is use the double quotes at the first place, for the values, use single quotes.
->select(DB::raw("CASE WHEN user_status='new' THEN 'New'  ELSE 'Expired' END AS new_status"))  
Cannot use single quote from the beginning. My god.... 
Thank You!!!!!!!!!!!!!